# Why variable from mod file is not changed when something function in executed

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is not the `some` variable changed to `other strings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `module.exports.some = some;` line in `mod.js` only exported the value of the `some` variable **at the time the line was executed**. In this case, the exported value was `"String exec"`.